# Respawn an enemy prefab after its destroyed

Tags: unity-game-engine, instance

```
var respawn : Transform;
var dead : boolean = false;

function OnTriggerEnter(theCollision : Collider)
{
   if(theCollision.gameObject.name=="Spotlight") 
   {
     Destroy(gameObject);
     Debug.Log("Dead");
     dead = true;

   }
}


function Respawn()
{

    if(dead == true)
    {
       Instantiate(respawn, Vector3(0,0,0), Quaternion.identity);
    }

}
```

I'm having trouble getting my enemies to re-spawn, at the moment I have just the one enemy following me around. I'm trying to re-spawn his after he collides with my spotlight.

I have a prefab Enemy that I want to use to create more instances of Enemy once it gets destroyed.

I'm pretty sure my code above is destroying the prefab itself and thus cannot create any more instances but I'm not sure how to just destroy an instance of a prefab. The code above is attached to my enemy.

Comment: You would need a script on your respawner to keep track of the living enemies, and when all are dead, wait a bit to then spawn another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you need to keep track of the time since the enemy died, and the best place to do that is in your respawner object. Here is an example implementation of it:

#### Respawner.js

```
#pragma strict

var enemyToSpawn : Enemy;
var respawnTime : int = 10; //In seconds.
private var dead : boolean = true;
private var deadTime : int = 0; //Time the enemy died, keep at 0
private var nextRespawn : int = 0; 

private function Respawn() {
    var enemy : GameObject = GameObject.Instantiate(enemyToSpawn.gameObject, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    enemy.GetComponent(Enemy).respawner = this;
}

function Update() {
    if (Time.time >= nextRespawn && dead) { //If the time is due and the enemy is dead
        Respawn(); //create a new enemy
        dead = false; //and tell our script it is alive
    }
}

function EnemyDied(theEnemy : Enemy) {
    dead = true;
    deadTime = Time.time;
    nextRespawn = Time.time+respawnTime;
    GameObject.Destroy(theEnemy.gameObject);
}
```

#### Enemy.js

```
#pragma strict

public var respawner : Respawner; // The respawner associated with this enemy

function OnTriggerEnter(collision : Collider) {
    if (collision.gameObject.name.Equals("Spotlight")) {
        respawner.SendMessage("EnemyDied", this); //Tell the respawner to kill us
    }
}
```

Of course your enemy class will have anything else necessary to be an actual enemy, and your respawner could have an effect. *This is just an example and shouldn't be blindly copy-pasted.*

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you are destroying the `gameObject` with the script.

```
if(theCollision.gameObject.name=="Spotlight") 
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
    Debug.Log("Dead");
    dead = true;
}
```

You should have there `Destroy(theCollision.gameObject)` instead.

And destroy at the end of the code block, not beginning.

Also `Respawn` function should be on `Update` or something for it to work, also you can call `Respawn` on the trigger function before destroying and it should spawn a new one every time.

Do not forget to reference the prefab from you `Project` window not `Hierarchy`.

Comment: Could you put this in text, rather than an image?

Comment: I took a screenshot from the original code... I did not modify it. I am just saying a line there should change.

Comment: Yes, and I think it needs to be added here in text format. Text trapped in images does not work with clipboards, search engine robots and screen-readers, and is thus a non-optimal way to present code.